# How to solve Mailgun Connection Timed Out Error Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, laravel-5

I am using Mailgun, it was working fine locally (Xampp) but when i deployed app to server it is throwing this error.

> Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 269: Connection
>   could not be established with host smtp.mailgun.org [Connection timed
>   out #110]

PS : I tried some answers, by changing encryption_type to tls and replacing smpt with IP but none work.

**.env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mailgunSMTPLogin
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: can you telnet from your server to smtp.mailgun.org or atleast ping.

Comment: Pinging smtp.mailgun.org [104.130.177.23] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 104.130.177.23: bytes=32 time=293ms TTL=249
Reply from 104.130.177.23: bytes=32 time=284ms TTL=249
Reply from 104.130.177.23: bytes=32 time=334ms TTL=249
Reply from 104.130.177.23: bytes=32 time=325ms TTL=249

Ping statistics for 104.130.177.23:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 284ms, Maximum = 334ms, Average = 309ms

Comment: thats good.. can you try telnet with ip and port

Answer (score 0):

I had this mailgun error recently and I fixed it by changing the mail encryption and port values in my .env file

```
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=SSL
```

and it's working for me